# Dojo, creating composite widgets

Tags: dojo, widget, composition

I am using dojo 1.10 and am desperately trying to find a clean way to create composite widgets,

I have the following code:

```
TabsWidget.js

require([......], function(.....template ....){

var Tabs = declare('...', [....], {

 templateString : template,
 region : 'center'

});

var o = new Tabs({}, 'container');

widget.startup();

});

TabsWidget.html


<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
     <div-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="..">
           ......Content pane........
     </div>
</div>

home.html

......
 <div data-dojo-type="TabsWidget"></div>
```

The tabs render fine, they are obviously empty tabs and the goal here is to then define a seperate widget containing a grid and perhaps a search form.

I then want to declare this widget within one of my content panes but am unsure how to do this.

Can anyone explain how this works or point me to a tutorial/document specifying how best to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Dojo doc on [creating template-based widgets](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/templated/index.html).

To use your TabsWidget as a standard widget, it needs to be organized a bit differently. In particular:

1. Use `define` to define your widget module, not `require`
2. Return a declared class from your module.

So more like:

```
define([ ... ], function ( ..., template, ...) {
   return declare([ ... ], {
       templateString: template,
       ...
   });
 });
```

Also, you would generally set the 'region' property when creating your widget, not when defining it. Your widget itself probably doesn't use 'region'; it's meant to tell a container where to put a widget. So:

```
<div data-dojo-type="TabsWidget" data-dojo-props="region:center"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks very much for the pointers, i have amended. Sadly when trying to put a widget within one of my ContentPane i see the div that the widget is meant to attach onto but nothing else. I have made this widget progromatically. Is there a requirement to specify a startup method, i have specified myGrid.startup() in post create but i get nothing, not even an error message.

Comment: Assuming your ContentPane is accessible as the variable `contentPane` and the thing you want to be its content is `widget`, you would set the content with `contentPane.set('content', widget);`.

Comment: I see, managed to get the contentPane in by doing this, i see a single div being added with my widgets id but does not look like widget is starting up

Comment: A widget added to a container such as a ContentPane will be automatically started when the container is started. A widget will also be started if the container was already started when the widget was added. If you have a bunch of nested widgets on a page, make sure the top-level one is started and, assuming its descendants have been added using widget methods (like `set('content', ...)`), everything should be started.

Comment: Thankyou, grid now appears in the dom node as it should, however i only get a grey box where my LazyGridTree should be, another issue so I will accept your answer(s) for original question. Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

in order to achieve this easily you can create a parent template based widget with one parent div in that ex: `<div data-dojo-attach-point="parentDiv"> </div>`and place your tab or content pane in this and then create another template based widget separately and you can instantiate that widget (which contains a grid or search box) from parent widget and place that widget in the content pane div tag. You can emit events from child widgets so that any function can be triggered on that event.

Tutor for creating template based widget in dojo : http://haritechtalk.blogspot.in/2015/09/how-to-create-template-based-widget-in.html